# Tensor of cocomplete categories

Tags: category-theory, tensor-products

Let $C$, $D$ and $E$ be cocomplete categories.

Is there a construction $C \otimes D$ such that there is a correspondence between functors $C \otimes D \to E$ preserving colimits and functors $C \times D \to E$ preserving colimits in each of its compontents ("bilinear")? How can I construct it? Why not?

Comment: This should at least be the case if $C$ and $D$ are presentable.

Comment: I think it is just true in general, though you might have to give up some things like local smallness. Do it by generators and relations like any other tensor product.

Comment: I have asked this before on mathoverflow.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Could you link the question on MO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, I will discuss categories with colimits of $\kappa$-small diagrams, where $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal. Specifically, consider the following category $\mathbf{K}$:

- The objects are small categories equipped with *chosen* $\kappa$-ary coproducts and coequalisers of parallel pairs.
- The morphisms are functors that *strictly* preserve the chosen colimits.

By standard arguments, $\mathbf{K}$ is a locally $\kappa$-presentable category. Given objects $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{B}$, and $\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathbf{K}$, define the following set:
$$\mathbf{K} (\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} ; \mathcal{C}) = \{ F \in \mathrm{Fun} (\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}, \mathcal{C}) : F \text{ strictly preserves colimits in each variable} \}$$
It is easy to see that $\mathbf{K} (\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} ; -) : \mathbf{K} \to \mathbf{Set}$ preserves all limits and also $\kappa$-filtered colimits. Thus, by the accessible adjoint functor theorem, it is represented by some object $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ in $\mathbf{K}$. Unfortunately, everything here is strict, so this doesn't quite do what we want.

The core issue is this: given objects $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ in $\mathbf{K}$, there may be functors $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ that preserve (up to isomorphism) colimits of $\kappa$-small diagrams that are *not* isomorphic to any functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ that *strictly* preserve the chosen colimits. If I understand the general theory correctly, this can be fixed: there exist an object $\tilde{\mathcal{C}}$ in $\mathbf{K}$ and a morphism $p : \tilde{\mathcal{C}} \to \mathcal{C}$ in $\mathbf{K}$ that is fully faithful and essentially surjective on objects such that there are enough morphisms $\tilde{\mathcal{C}} \to \mathcal{D}$.

Thus, given $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ in $\mathbf{K}$, the desired tensor product is not $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ itself but rather $\tilde{\mathcal{A}} \otimes \tilde{\mathcal{B}}$. I'm afraid I do not have a more explicit description of this category, but all of this is basically a souped-up version of the usual construction of tensor products by generators and relations.

Comment: Where can I read about the accessible adjoint functor theorem? What about the existence of $ \tilde{\mathcal{C}}$?

Comment: The accessible adjoint functor theorem is described in Adamek/Rosicky and also Borceux. The second thing, I don't think is described in textbooks.